# How to convert a Map of Map to Map of Object using Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have an class with a Builder:

```
Student.builder().name("Name").email("Email").phone("Phone").build();
```

```
class Student {
    String name;
    String email;
    String phone; 
}
```

I have a `Map<String, Map<String, String>` to convert to `Map<String, Student>`

```
("GroupA", ("name", "Steve"))
("GroupA", ("email", "steve@gmail.com"))
("GroupA", ("phone", "111-222-3333"))
("GroupB", ("name", "Alice"))
("GroupB", ("email", "alice@gmail.com"))
("GroupB", ("phone", "111-222-4444"))
("GroupC", ("name", "Bobby"))
("GroupC", ("email", "bobby@gmail.com"))
("GroupC", ("phone", "111-222-5555"))
```

I am trying to using Stream to make the code a bit cleaner but not sure how to accomplish this. What I have with normal Java code

```
Map<String, Student> newStudentMap = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<String, Map<String, String>> entry : studentMap.entrySet()) {
    Map<String, String> value = entry.getValue();
    Student student = Student.builder()
            .name(value.get("name"))
            .email(value.get("email")))
            .phone(value.get("phone"))
            .build();
    newStudentMap.put(entry.getKey(), student);
}
```

Comment: I think your map of maps already contains a problem. Your shouldn't store data like this. It would be more sufficient, if you would start with a Map<String, String[]>. In the way you do it, you wouldn't know which email belongs to which name etc... Then you would just have to call the constructor...

Comment: How do you expect to make a Student out of a Map or Object unless that Object is actually instance of Student ?

Comment: How come your map has multiple entries with the same key ("GroupA")?

Comment: Sorry, copy & paste issue. I'll fix it. I also added the more info.

Comment: By converting you meant create an new instance of the Map? Because there is no way you can change the datatype of the old map from `Map<String, Map<String, String>` to `Map<String, Student>`. If that's what you meant, doing it in the stream will depend on an instance outside of the lambda function, IMO it defeats the condense syntax stream provides to you

Comment: yes, I am creating a new map. I posted my current Java code to make it clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Map<String, Student> newStudentMap = studentMap.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
    Map.Entry::getKey, 
    e -> Student.builder()
           .name(e.getValue().get("name"))
           .email(e.getValue().get("email"))
           .phone(e.getValue().get("phone"))
           .build()
    ));
```

How it works:

You take the entry set of your map, stream it and then collect to a new map using the `Collectors.toMap` collector that accepts two functions (key mapper and value mapper) used to create keys and values for a new map. You need the key from your original map, so you simply pass the method reference `Map.Entry::getKey` to take the key from the entry. And to create a new value you pass a function that takes `Map.Entry e` and creates a new `Student` from it